# Perguntas no Python (Try and except)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa que calcula a nota de um simulado estilo ENEM da minha escola, pergunto quantas questões de cada área a pessoa acertou, porém, quero fazer com que caso a pessoa digite um número inválido na segunda ou na terceira pergunta o programa refaça a questão em si e não o segmento todo.

```
while True:
    try:
        nh = int(input("Quantas quesõtes de HUMANAS você acertou? "))
        if nh < 0 or nh > 45:
            print("Número inválido!")
            print()
            cls()
            continue

        nn = int(input("Quantas quesõtes de NATUREZAS você acertou? "))
        if nn < 0 or nn > 45:
            print("Número inválido!")
            print()
            cls()
            continue

        nl = int(input("Quantas quesõtes de LINGUAGENS você acertou? "))
        if nl < 0 or nl > 45:
            print("Número inválido!")
            print()
            cls()
            continue

        nm = int(input("Quantas quesõtes de MATEMÁTICA você acertou? "))
        if nm < 0 or nm > 45:
            print("Número inválido!")
            print()
            cls()
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("Você não digitou um número válido !")
        print()
        cls()
        continue
# programa segue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode automatizar as perguntas numa função:

```
def perguntar(area):
    try:
        n = int(input("Quantas questões de {} você acertou? ".format(area)))
    except ValueError:
        n = -1
    return n
```

Crie um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) para armazenar as áreas e respostas, e com o `for` passe a área para a pergunta:

```
areas = {'HUMANAS': 0, 'NATUREZAS': 0, 'LINGUAGENS': 0, 'MATEMÁTICA': 0}
perguntarNovamente = None

while True:
    for area in areas:
        # ...
```

Para refazer a pergunta novamente ao usuário caso seja digitado um valor fora do intervalo, use uma variável de controle:

```
perguntarNovamente = True

while perguntarNovamente:
    resposta = perguntar(area)

    if resposta < 0 or resposta > 45:
        print ("O número digitado é inválido! Tente novamente.")
        continue
    else:
        areas[area] = resposta
        perguntarNovamente = False
        break
```

Para mostrar as áreas e respostas, faça:

```
for area, resposta in areas.items():
    print ("Na área {} você acertou {} questões".format(area, resposta))

# programa segue...
break
```

Código  completo:

```
def perguntar(area):
    try:
        n = int(input("Quantas questões de {} você acertou? ".format(area)))
    except ValueError:
        n = -1
    return n

areas = {'HUMANAS': 0, 'NATUREZAS': 0, 'LINGUAGENS': 0, 'MATEMÁTICA': 0}
perguntarNovamente = None

while True:
    for area in areas:
        perguntarNovamente = True

        while perguntarNovamente:
            resposta = perguntar(area)

            if resposta < 0 or resposta > 45:
                print ("O número digitado é inválido! Tente novamente.")
                continue
            else:
                areas[area] = resposta
                perguntarNovamente = False
                break

    for area, resposta in areas.items():
        print ("Na área {} você acertou {} questões".format(area, resposta))


    # programa segue...
    break
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/DNcv)</kbd>

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Valeu pela edição!